How to use ILogger.BeginScope in Blazor Server for the entire activity?
In a standard request/response app with AspNet.Core, it was easy to add informations to the request context so that every single log entry could have access to them automatically. For exemple, if I need that all my log entries have the logged UserName and the FormId that he is presently editing, I just had to create a new Middleware that use ILogger.BeginScope to achieve that and register the middleware at the beginning of the pipeline.
public class FormLogEnricherMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly IMyForm _myForm;
    private readonly ILogger<FormLogEnricherMiddleware > _logger;

    public FormLogEnricherMiddleware(IMyForm myForm, ILogger<FormLogEnricherMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _myForm = myForm;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var scopeTags = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            ["UserName"] = context.User?.Identity?.Name,
            ["FormId"] = _myForm.FormId
        };

        using (_logger.BeginScope(scopeTags))
        {
            return next(context);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
...
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddScoped<FormLogEnricherMiddleware>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<FormLogEnricherMiddleware>();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
...

HomeController.cs
_logger.LogInformation("This is a test");

Result

Now that we use Blazor Server with web sockets, the middleware way is not working anymore. So how can we add informations in a ILogger scope so that every log have access to them automatically?
